# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. Laravel issue

Tags: laravel

I'm very new to using Laravel and these things so please excuse me for my stupidity, but I am getting this error when trying to create a project.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVUR1.png

Comment: Welcome to SO...  You need to provide more context, What are you trying to do when you get this error. What code or command are you trying to execute

Comment: Read the error message. You don't have a required extension

Answer (score 1):

as stated in the error your php installation does not meet the requirements(missing extension). To solve current error you need to uncomment `extension=fileinfo` line in your `php.ini` file

Comment: Thank you very much Sante. Much appreciated, I just had to remove the ; in the ini file.